# How to display selected textarea value in html

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have textarea on simple html form. I want to display selected value of that text area just like selected value in dropdown. I searched google where I found textarea has no value attribute. So is there any option to display selected textarea value in html?

**I want to show it's value while editing form just like selected value in dropdown list while editing..**

Comment: Use "innerHTML" of javascript to display its value. of .html() function of jquery.

Comment: @Purushottamzende can you show me some syntax??

Comment: conidering the id of the textarea is "text1" it will be document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "new value";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put like this..and it's working..

```
<textarea name="yojana" id="yojana"cols="50" rows="3"><?php echo $delivery_memo_info->yojana;?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this coding..

```
$('#formId :textarea').click(function() {
   alert(this.tagName != 'TEXTAREA' ? this.tagName : this.type);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps you

http://plnkr.co/edit/ocl4Zcmv4qjXSIxE7IyF?p=preview

jQuery not required. With plain Java Script, you can achieve this functionality.

HTML :

```
<textarea id='123' onkeyup='getvalue()'>
  TEXTAREA
</textarea>
```

JS :

```
function getvalue(){

 var a = document.getElementById('123').value;

 alert(a)

}
```

Comment: I want it on body onload..I want to show it's value while editing the form.

Comment: Now, could you please check the plunker link once. Is that you want?

Comment: sorry..No I dont want like that..I solved the problem and posted my answer also..